# What D&D manual describes this game dragons play?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, product-identification, dragons, content-identification, plot-hooks

In a D&D manual, I once read about a game that dragons play against each other. They use kingdoms as pawns and the games can last decades or centuries.

What book is the game in or what is the game called? I would love to use the scenario for my campaign.

Comment: This is the first time I've tagged a question as both product _and_ content identification. Neat.

Answer (score 34):

It's called Xorvintaal. *Monster Manual V* (3.5) has some information on it, and there may be more in certain 4e books.

The actual *rules* for the game are enormously convoluted, taking "years to learn, and centuries to master". One would be forgiven for thinking they'd fit right in with published sourcebooks on that score, but instead the designers left the specifics up to DMs, with the idea that players should generally have only a vague idea of exactly what's going on.

Comment: 3.5 has a Draconomicon, pretty sure it is not in there.

Comment: @Me_Maikey No, but it *is* in the 4e Draconomicons, AFAIK.

Comment: Confirmed that MMV 3.5 has information and Draconomicon 3.5 does not. I do not have 4e books to check :(.

Comment: http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Xorvintaal contains links to additional books that contain The Game.

Comment: @phyrfox: When I checked those, they appeared to be novels, and two of them had almost the same blurb, so I decided to leave them out.

Comment: I just checked both 4E Draconomicons - no mention of Xorvintaal.

Comment: Xorvintaal mentioned in a campaign setting (aria of the dragon slayers iirc, the one with the sand dragons at the end) and in monster manual of 4E but no rules

Answer (score 8):

As TuggyNE says, the game you are thinking of, Xorvintaal, is described in only vague details in *Monster Manual V* in order to leave things free and open to DMs to figure out the way they want. He does, however, seem to lament the fact that the details are quite *so* sparse, and thus I want to offer this: [Elements of the Great Game](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?530332-Xorvintaal-the-Great-Game&p=22197639#post22197639) by afroakuma. Afro is one of the best sources of D&D-lore knowledge on the internet, and his ideas here are, I think, excellent.

> The following [linked above] are some of the fragmentary rules, gambits, methods, and principles sages have managed to in some way distill from decades of observing the Great Game in action. Note that the nature of Xorvintaal means that any or all of these might be misinterpretations, false assumptions based on unverified information, or local or conditional rules - the depth of Xorvintaal is simply too great to reasonably appreciate, its rules too ingrained in unspoken tradition and ritual to be accessible.